# Template deduction interesting case, c++

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, type-deduction

Consider this peace of code:

```
template<class T>
void f(const T& t)
{
    static int x = 0;
    cout<<++x<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    const int i = 0;
    f(5);
    f(i);
    f(j);
}
```

I have called the function for 3 types. Although 5 and j can be the same thing, just int, const int i is definitely different type.
But anyway my output is:

```
1
2
3
```

So that means that compiler instantiates the same function for different types.
Am I correct? Can anybody explain why?

Comment: Because that's how templates work! :-)

Comment: Printing the address of `x`, via `cout << &x << endl;` might be a simpler way to identify which is being called. Best of all is `cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;`, but that's not guaranteed to be in all compilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [temp.deduct.call]:

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it P) with
>   the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it A) as described below.

`P` is `const T&` and `A` is `int`, `int`, and `const int` in the three calls.

We then have:

> If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction.

`P` is a reference type, so we use `P' == const T` for deduction against `A == int` or `A == const int`. In both cases, we deduce `T == int` so that `P' == const int` (and `P == const int&`) and the deduced `A == const int`. This is more *cv*-qualified than the original `A` for the first two calls, but that's explicitly made OK:

> In general, the deduction process attempts to find template argument values that will make the deduced A
>   identical to A (after the type A is transformed as described above). However, there are three cases that allow
>   a difference:
>   — If the original P is a reference type, the deduced A (i.e., the type referred to by the reference) can be
>   more cv-qualified than the transformed A.

Thus, all three cases just call `f<int>`.

Comment: I think inserting an *otherwise* between those two sentences might be just an editorial issue; maybe submit a github issue?

Comment: @dyp I do not actually know how to do that

Comment: Via https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues . There's a green "New issue" button on the top right, maybe only if you have a github account (and are logged in). The relevant part is here: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/source/templates.tex#L6148

Comment: @dyp Thinking about it some more, you're definitely right. `template <typename T> void foo(T& )` cannot drop top-level cv-qualifiers on `A`. So there can't be that sort of recursion. I'm not sure of a better way to word it though, so I don't know what I would propose.

Comment: Well I thought something like *If `P` is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of `P`'s type are ignored for type deduction; otherwise, if `P` is a reference type, the type referred to by `P` is used for type deduction.* Or maybe even better by reversing those two sentences, which makes it more obvious that a reference type is not cv-qualified.

Comment: @dyp Submitted something along those lines.

Answer (score 5):

Here `f` will be instantiated one time, for type `int`, since all 3 calls call just `f<int>`.

Comment: Might want to explain why `i` and `j` are the same

Comment: The best question might be "why is `T` not `const int` when using `j`?".

Answer (score 0):

It's correct as soon as type deduction is valid.

Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
void f(const T& t)
{
    static int x = 0;
    std::cout<< "x=" << ++x<<std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void f(T&& t)
{
    static int y = 0;
    std::cout<< "y=" << ++y<<std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void f(T& t)
{
    static int z = 0;
    std::cout<< "z=" << ++z<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int j = 0;
    const int i = 0;
    f(5);
    f(i);
    f(j);
}
```

Output:

```
y=1
x=1
z=1
```